# Replacing div data with other divs jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I click on any link it's names should up in above banner, like sr no 1 name is jack and smith then TEST1 should replace by jack and test2 by smith and when i click on other name then in place of jack and smith those names should show and i have 100+ data names so i need  just a simple few lines jQuery code which will do that without refreshing my page... and one more thing when page loads then TEST1 and TEST2 should show auto 1st name...

Sorry I did a lot of typing but starter here please help

```
 <div style="border:1px solid black;">
  <div style="display:inline; margin-left:20%;">
    <img style="display:inline;" src="images/soccer-ball.png" height="50px" width="50px">
    <p id="h1" style="display:inline;" placeholder="Test">TEST1</p>
  </div>
  <div style="display:inline; margin-left:30%;">
    <img style="display:inline;" src="images/soccer-ball.png" height="50px" width="50px">
    <p id="h2" style="display:inline;">TEST2</p>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <a href="#" id="link" style="color: inherit; text-decoration: none;">
    <div style="border:1px solid black;">
      <div style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid black;">
        <p>Sr no 1</p>
      </div>
      <div style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid black;">
        <p id="home">jack</p>
        <p id="away">Smith</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" id="link" style="color: inherit; text-decoration: none;">
    <div style="border:1px solid black;">
      <div style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid black;">
        <p>Sr no 2</p>
      </div>
      <div style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid black;">
        <p id="home">Jhon</p>
        <p id="away">hill</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" id="link" style="color: inherit; text-decoration: none;">
    <div style="border:1px solid black;">
      <div style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid black;">
        <p>Sr no 3</p>
      </div>
      <div style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid black;">
        <p>jason</p>
        <p>smantha</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" id="link" style="color: inherit; text-decoration: none;">
    <div style="border:1px solid black;">
      <div style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid black;">
        <p>Sr no 4</p>
      </div>
      <div style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid black;">
        <p>Ducan</p>
        <p>Gio</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#h1").replaceWith($('#home').text());
 $("#h2").replaceWith($('#away').text());
});
$("#link").click(function(){
    var x = $("#home").html();
    var y = $("#away").html();
    //alert(x);
    $("#h1").html(x);
    $("#h2").html(y);
   });
```

Comment: I have updated jquerry code when i load my page 1st persons data show automatically but when i click on 2nd person it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not assign the same id to multiple html elements (it is malformed and jQuery won't be able to find the elements you intend). In addition, you forgot to set attributes for some of the names that you want to populate at the top. Finally, you are using `replaceWith()` which is removing the elements that you are then looking to update later on click. I changed several of your ids to classes, filled in the missing ones, and updated your jQuery to eliminate the `replaceWith()` issue and work with the class approach. See below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#h1").html($(".home").first().text());
  $("#h2").html($(".away").first().text());
});

$(".link").click(function() {
  var x = $(this).find(".home").first().html();
  var y = $(this).find(".away").first().html();
  $("#h1").html(x);
  $("#h2").html(y);
});
```

```html
<div style="border:1px solid black;">
  <div style="display:inline; margin-left:20%;">
    <img style="display:inline;" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" height="50px" width="50px">
    <p id="h1" style="display:inline;" placeholder="Test">TEST1</p>
  </div>
  <div style="display:inline; margin-left:30%;">
    <img style="display:inline;" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" height="50px" width="50px">
    <p id="h2" style="display:inline;">TEST2</p>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <a href="#" class="link" style="color: inherit; text-decoration: none;">
    <div style="border:1px solid black;">
      <div style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid black;">
        <p>Sr no 1</p>
      </div>
      <div style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid black;">
        <p class="home">jack</p>
        <p class="away">Smith</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="link" style="color: inherit; text-decoration: none;">
    <div style="border:1px solid black;">
      <div style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid black;">
        <p>Sr no 2</p>
      </div>
      <div style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid black;">
        <p class="home">Jhon</p>
        <p class="away">hill</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="link" style="color: inherit; text-decoration: none;">
    <div style="border:1px solid black;">
      <div style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid black;">
        <p>Sr no 3</p>
      </div>
      <div style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid black;">
        <p class="home">jason</p>
        <p class="away">smantha</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="link" style="color: inherit; text-decoration: none;">
    <div style="border:1px solid black;">
      <div style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid black;">
        <p>Sr no 4</p>
      </div>
      <div style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid black;">
        <p class="home">Ducan</p>
        <p class="away">Gio</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```